# Use of CASE in Update query

Tags: sql

I have following SQL (Using MS SQL)

```
UPDATE AR_Slots
SET Running = @Running,
StopSignal = @StopSignal,
WHERE (SlotId = @SlotId)
```

I want to set a field called RunListID to 0 if Running parameter (boolean) is true otherwise I don't want to change the value at all.

What is the "correct" way of doing this?

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
UPDATE AR_Slots
SET RunListID = 
    CASE
       WHEN <your check value>
          THEN 0
       ELSE RunListID
    END,
    <your other sets>
WHERE <your criteria>
```

Comment: I agree that the above solution would work. I would add that even setting the RunListID back to its original value is seen as a change to the DB.  If an index or trigger is associated with this field then if will rebuild the index or execute the trigger.  Therefore having a separate SQL for this update might be an option if performance is key.

Comment: Thanks for that! I was unsure what ever I could use the actual RunListID and just set it again.